# To group data by rows column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How to group data by rows column?

*query*:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT MONTH(T1.SPL_CreateDate) AS DateMonth,
           T1.SPL_EngagementCount,
           T1.SPL_ViewCount
    FROM LP_SocialPostLog T1
) T2
GROUP BY T2.DateMonth, SPL_EngagementCount, SPL_ViewCount
```

*result*:

```
DateMonth   SPL_EngagementCount SPL_ViewCount
1            0                   1
1            1                   0
2            0                   1
```

I want results:

```
DateMonth   SPL_EngagementCount SPL_ViewCount
1            1                   1
2            0                   1
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `SUM` you can aggregate the other two columns

```
  SELECT DateMonth, 
         sum(SPL_EngagementCount) SPL_EngagementCount, 
         sum(SPL_ViewCount) SPL_ViewCount
    FROM (SELECT MONTH(T1.SPL_CreateDate) AS DateMonth, 
                 T1.SPL_EngagementCount, 
                 T1.SPL_ViewCount 
            FROM LP_SocialPostLog T1
         ) T2
GROUP BY T2.DateMonth
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this :

```
SELECT Month(SPL_CreateDate)    AS [DateMonth],
       Sum(SPL_EngagementCount) AS [SPL_EngagementCount],
       Sum(SPL_ViewCount)       AS [SPL_ViewCount]
FROM   LP_SocialPostLog
GROUP  BY Month(SPL_CreateDate)
```

Note: if you want the maximum then use `max()` instead of `sum()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want this?

```
SELECT MONTH(T1.SPL_CreateDate) AS DateMonth
  ,SUM(T1.SPL_EngagementCount) as SPL_EngagementCount
  ,SUM(T1.SPL_ViewCount) as SPL_ViewCount
FROM LP_SocialPostLog T1
GROUP BY MONTH(T1.SPL_CreateDate)
```

Comment: Ha - Like Deepak said! Beaten to it :-)

Comment: What I do not understand what you mean :/ but we were all created by Allah c.c :) Thank you for answer